# Inserted pdfpages header consumes extra table numbers in TOC/LOT

Tags: header-footer, pdfpages

I’d like a tabular header to appear on each page of the pdf I’m including. So I am using these commands in `pdfpages`.

```
\def\plotheader{
\setlength\LTleft{0.85in}
\begin{longtable}{p{2.7in}p{2.7in}p{2.7in}}
A & B & C
\end{longtable}}

\includepdf[pages={-},angle=90, offset=15mm 0mm, width=5in,height=8.3in, pagecommand={TEST \\ \plotheader}, addtolist={ 1, figure, title, tab:mytable}]{plot.pdf}`
```

What ends up happening is that the tabular plot header consumes more than one table number, even though it is a figure. As a result, there is a discontinuity in the list of tables in the TOC. How can I avoid this?

Comment: The `addtolist` option has precisely this effect, that's what it was created for. If you delete it, it should be ok.

Comment: Don't use `longtable` but a simple tabular instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks for spotting that! I was using the longtable environment specifically because I could use the `p{Xin}` option. I am not sure that the tabular environment supports the option. If it doesn't, do you know of any other tabular environment options that support fixed width columns? @CountZero I am sorry I wasn't clear - the addtolist, in this case consumes more than one table number in the TOC. In fact it consumes as many pages as there are in the pdfpages.I just want the whole multipage plot to have just one entry in the TOC. I have edited the Q a bit now.

Comment: @Ariel: `tabular` *does* support `p{<len>}` columns.

Comment: @Ariel: I don't see anything wrong. Your `\includepdf` produces a *single* LoF entry for the *first* page. If you want an evenly distributed column setup for you table across the entire `\textwidth`, use the [`tabularx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) with its `X` column type.

Comment: @Werner: The problem of Ariel was not the (number of) entries in the list of figures (or list of tables) and has nothing to do with the `\includepdf` options. The problem was the table counter itself: He uses a longtable in the header and each of this `longtable` increases the table counter and so there are suddenly gaps in the numbering of his normal tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `longtable` in the header. It doesn't make sense there as you don't need a page break and it disturbs the numbering of your normal tables as it increase the table counter internally. Use a simple `tabular` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Combined with @Werner's helpful comment above, I replaced the longtable in the header with tabularx: `\def\plotheader{\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} \begin{tabularx}{8.3in}{YYY} A & B & C \end{tabularx}}` The counter in the list of tables is now displaying correctly.